# INSERT commands fail when double quotes are inside a text string

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I recently got some problems when inserting a text string which contains a double quote in the database.
I used the filter_var to sanitize and filter the input.

Example:

```
$filtered = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
```

When entering a string 'a"b' it gets converted into 'a"b'
Thus, when I print out the insert command it looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO its_info (ID, Title) VALUES(13, "a&#34;b");
```

What happens now is that when the actual database insert is performed not the above query is used, but

```
INSERT INTO its_info (ID, Title) VALUES(13, "a"b");
```

Off course this is faulty and this command fails.

Wondering why this double quote gets converted again.
Checked the settings in php.ini. All settings look normal
I tried other options for filter_var like FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS and FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES, but this didn't work too.

PHP 5.6.24 / PDO extension / MySQL 5.1.73

Answer (score 1):

You should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) when sending data to the RDBMS, then you would not need to perform any magical sanitization operations. You probably should also watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) (it explains what prepared statements are .. it uses MySQLi in the examples, but it works just the same with PDO).

### Wrong way

```
$pdo->query('INSERT INTO its_info (ID, Title) VALUES(13, "' . $title . '")');
```

### Correct way

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO its_info (ID, Title) VALUES(13, :title)');
$stmt->bindValue(':title', $title);
$stmt->execute();
```

---

And, if you are using PDO with MySQL/MariaDB, you should disable emulation of prepared statements. The establishing of connection should looks something like this:

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:......;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape a string variable in manual mode:

```
$str = str_replace('"', '\\"', $str);
```